# Is there a way to increase a creature's size category twice?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, creature-size

The Enlarge/Reduce spell can make a creature one size category bigger.

Considering that two spell effects of the same nature cannot stack at the same place and time (you can't cast two Enlarges on the same Medium target to make it Huge), is there another way (spell, item, etc.) to increase a target's size category that could be stacked with the Enlarge effect in order to increase the target's size category twice ?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

#### I believe it is possible if you're one lucky WM sorcerer.

Per the Wild Magic sorcerer's Wild Magic Surge table (PHB, p. 104), if you roll the d100 and get a result of 93-94:

> Your size increases by one size category for the next minute.

It doesn't specify that you cast *enlarge/reduce* on yourself. In other cases, it explicitly states that you "cast" spells:

> You **cast** *fireball* as a 3rd-level spell centered on yourself.
> You **cast** *magic missile* as a 5th-level spell.

and so on.

So *enlarge/reduce* the spell and the wild magic enlarge effect aren't spell effects of the same name and can be stacked.

Comment: I think, contrasting with keithcurtis' answer, that it'd be worth pointing out not only that you're not *casting* enlarge, but also you're not even *gaining the effect* of enlarge. Your size is just changing, so there is no question of effects stacking.

Comment: @nitsua60 Fair point, I'm still new to tabletop RPGs and their rulings, just wanted to do one's bit.

Answer (score 10):

Enlarge would stack with the spell polymorph or the druid's Wild Shape feature, which allow you to assume a different size category, based on the shape. If you want to remain the same creature type, I don't think you can.

Using a Potion of Growth might require a DM call, since it says it duplicates the effect of the enlarge/reduce spell, but is not actually the spell itself. I think most DMs would disallow the combination, but since the potion is a consumable, DM-controlled resource, it's unlikely to become unbalancing.

Answer (score 3):

Level 14+ [Giant Soul Sorcerers (Unearthed Arcana)](https://media.wizards.com/2018/dnd/downloads/UA_GiantSoul.pdf) can use *Rage of Fallen Ostoria*, letting them increase size category by 1 for a minute, once per short rest.

> Starting   at  14th    level,  you gain    the ability to  channel the souls   of  your    ancestors   into    your    physical    form.   When    you start   casting a   sorcerer    spell   on  your    turn    and expend  a   spell   slot,   youcan increase your size   by one  category—from   Medium  to  Large,  for example.

You can either cast Enlarge on top of that, or wait until level 18, when you can use it twice per short rest, and are explicitly permitted to stack it on itself.

> In addition,   you can now use Rage    of  Fallen  Ostoria twice   between rests,  but no  more    than    once    on  a   turn.   If  you use that    feature while
>   under   its effects,    its increases   to  your size, hit  points, reach,  and walking speed   are cumulative.

Comment: Speaking of Unearthed Arcana, the recently published Rune Knight allows a similar thing ! (Becoming chunky)

Answer (score 2):

## For a Non-Player Character Duergar

[Monster Duergar](https://www.dndbeyond.com/monsters/duergar) have a once per short rest ability to gain similar effects to the enlarge part of the enlarge/reduce spell (it doubles weapon damage dice rather than adds 1d4 and requires no concentration, so usually superior). They become a large creature for the duration. Because this is a magical ability rather than a spell it can stack with the enlarge/reduce spell. And voila, you have a huge Dwarf.

The [player race Duergar](https://www.dndbeyond.com/races/dwarf#GrayDwarfDuergar) casts it as a spell, however, so unless you have a friendly NPC party member with the creature stats rather than player race stats there is probably not a time when you want to do this.

Answer (score 2):

Just get the Rune Knight (from Tasha's Cauldron of Everything) subclass from the fighter and then use the Enlarge/Reduction Spell. Use Giant Might first and then Enlarge. Now you are a Huge Creature on Level 3 (when another Party moember casts Enlarge, if not you would have to get another class with the Enlarge Spell, so with no Help you can become a Huge Creature on Level 6). (If i understood it right). Or you could just use the Gray Dwarf subrace and get the Rune Knight subclass. You can now cast Enlarge on yourself and become a Huge Creature in one turn and on Level 18 you become a Gargantuan Creature.

Answer (score 0):

How about a potion of giant size and then using enlarge/reduce spell as a stack. The first just states you gain the Huge trait; then using enlarge/reduce, you can therefore double the size of a creature.

Comment: You should probably quote and cite the things you're referring to, in particular the magic item as it might not be widely known. Also as terminology pedantry, it's Huge size, it's not a trait as such. (You can [edit] to include this, no need to mark the edit).

Comment: Oh and, Welcome to RPG.SE! Take the [tour] if you haven't already and see the [help] or ask us here in the comments (use @ to ping someone) if you need more guidance. Good Luck and Happy Gaming!

Comment: This needs editing more than it needs downvoting... It is (barring one misnomer) one of multiple correct answers, & not presented in the other answers here: _Potion of Giant Size_ & _Potion of Growth_ / _Enlarge/Reduce_ do stack (if applied in that order).

Answer (score -2):

Hummm... rune knight lvl 3 feral might... you become large.
Huge at lvl 18.    So with enlarge spell   boom.

Comment: Please expand this answer with further details by citing the relevant rules and explaining how they interact etc. While this answer may be correct [we expect a bit more detail and explanation](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/q/8696/14878).

Comment: Hi AJ it can help if you ad your source material too, e.g. book and page number. :)